# Flex vertical sliding thumbnails

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

Is it possible to construct an vertical sliding thumbnails of images.
The example is shown at following path:
http://www.rburman.com/#a=0&at=0&mi=2&pt=1&pi=10000&s=1&p=0

As i am new to flex Please suggest the solution or refer to any example with the source code. 
Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this must be one of the most requested things for flex to do. have you tried google?
anyway check out http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/08/creating-a-simple-image-gallery-with-the-flex-tilelist-control/
or

[adobe exchange](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?searchfield=gallery&search_exchange=15&search_category=-1&search_license=&search_rating=&search_platform=0&search_pubdate=&num=25&startnum=1&event=search&sticky=true&sort=0&Submit=)

or the [adobe photo gallery example](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/photo_explorer/)

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the support kenneth, but i am sorry for not describing the requirement properly.
Actually what i need is to slide down or slide up the thumbnails in the gallery with an rollover on it (without showing the scroll bar). ie sliding movement of images is required.

Comment: Then take a look at the examples and inside your viewing area turn off the scrollbar and use the rollOver, rollOut and mouseMove events to determine when mouse is in viewing area and where it is. Once you have that info it should just be a case of changing the position of the viewing area inside its container.
You may need to leave the scrollbars on, but make them invisable to change the containers overall position. If I see an exact example of what you're asking I'll update this.